# Cook something from/after a recipe?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions

When you cook something (Let's say "seafood pasta") by following a recipe, do you say "I am cooking seafood pasta from a recipe"?
i.e., Do you say "cook ... from a recipe"?
Or do you say "cook ... after a recipe?
Or else?

Comment: One question at a time, please. Ask your question about "recipe" separately.

Comment: Dear Nathan, thank you for your advise!  Then, I would like to ask about the second one: about a sentence.

Comment: You can [edit] to focus on whichever of the two questions you want, then ask the other one separately.

Comment: Dear Nathan, Thank you again! I didn't know this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, saying that we cook or make something **from a recipe** is perfectly idiomatic.  There are numerous examples extant:

> [She's been making stuffed peppers for years from a recipe off of a veggie crumbles package.](https://books.google.com/books?id=3UfT3Giae_AC&lpg=PP99&dq=%22from%20a%20recipe%22&pg=PP99#v=onepage&q=%22from%20a%20recipe%22&f=false)
>
> [...individual Yorkshire puddings made from a recipe I found...](https://books.google.com/books?id=pZ30lIcStVgC&lpg=PA19&dq=%22from%20a%20recipe%22&pg=PA19#v=onepage&q=%22from%20a%20recipe%22&f=false)
>
> [I still bake cookies from a recipe card in the handwriting of my mother...](https://books.google.com/books?id=3cxgAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PR11&dq=%22from%20a%20recipe%22&pg=PR11#v=onepage&q=%22from%20a%20recipe%22&f=false)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!  I can now be confident using a sentence with "from". I really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You usually "**[follow a recipe](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/recipe)**"

- Baking a cake isn't difficult - it's just a matter of *following the recipe*.
- I never *follow recipes* exactly when I cook - I just use them as rough guides.

However, you can also "cook a recipe":

- Yesterday, I cooked the "*Chicken doused in fresh coconut paste*" recipe and it was incredibly tasty.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!  I really appreciate your help.  Thank you!